Python semantic_kernel function 'No Service Found'
I am trying to follow this tutorial from Microsoft: tutorial.
I am using OPENAI_API.
But when I got to this point:
joke = await kernel.invoke(
    joke_function,
    KernelArguments(input="time travel to dinosaur age", style="super silly"),
)
print(joke)

I got the following error:
Something went wrong in function invocation. During function invocation: 'FunPlugin-Joke'. Error description: 'No service found.'
Error: Error occurred while invoking function: 'FunPlugin-Joke'

I put more logs before that function and print every log, so I think that part is the issue.
I copied everything from the .ipynb into a .py file and copied every file that I need but still I am getting the same error.
